# unit of work in a java 'main' application

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am doing this in each and every DAL method:

```
 public static Product GetProductByPartNumber(String partNumber)
    {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

         session.beginTransaction();


         Product product = (Product)session.createCriteria(Product.class)
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("partNumber", partNumber))
                                    .uniqueResult();
         session.getTransaction().commit();



         return product;
    }
```

This is causing problems, giving me 'session is closed' errors because of lazy loading etc.

How can I have getCurrentSession to not get a new session?

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

            //configuration.addClass(hsspider.Model.AMCategory.class);

            return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


}



 <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

I am guessing that is the problem, that the call to getCurrentSession is not getting the current session right?

Or does calling transaction.commit(); kill the session?
Should I just use flush?

Comment: transaction.commit() does not close the session .. It sounds like you may be closing the session yourself somewhere else in the Thread.  Which version of Hibernate are you using?  I know that in older versions you had to explicitly reconnect a session after you close the transaction, but you don't have to do that with the current version.

Comment: Bryan; the default session context *does* close the session when the transaction is committed. This is done because the ThreadLocalSessionContext cannot rely on any other hook for cleanup.

Comment: Why would you not just continue this conversation where it started?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029301/many-to-many-mapping-not-working-one-side-is-set-to-inverse/2029414#2029414

Comment: @delfuego that other thread seems to be a different question, so this one deserves another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the [`Transaction`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html) javadoc that I'm quoting below?

> Allows the application to define units of work, while maintaining abstraction from the underlying transaction implementation (eg. JTA, JDBC).
>
> A transaction is associated with a `Session` and is usually instantiated by a call to `Session.beginTransaction()`. A single session might span multiple transactions since the notion of a session (a conversation between the application and the datastore) is of coarser granularity than the notion of a transaction. However, it is intended that there be at most one uncommitted `Transaction` associated with a particular `Session` at any time.

And, about [`Transaction#commit()`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#commit%28%29):

> Flush the associated `Session` and end the unit of work (unless we are in [`FlushMode.NEVER`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#NEVER). This method will commit the underlying transaction if and only if the underlying transaction was initiated by this object.

This should answer your question: `commit()` doesn't kill the session (that can span multiple transaction as we saw).

Another good idea would be to put a breakpoint and to look at the internal details (you may need to tell your IDE where to find Hibernate sources for this).

I also suggest to check [Pluggable Session management in Hibernate 3.1](http://relation.to/Bloggers/PluggableSessionManagementInHibernate31) and the more recent [Sessions and transactions](https://www.hibernate.org/42.html) (especially [Transaction demarcation with plain JDBC](https://www.hibernate.org/42.html#A6)).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you use the [ThreadLocalSessionContex](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/context/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html). The interesting part of that javadoc is:

> it was decided to have this default
>   impl actually generate a session upon
>   first request and then clean it up
>   after the Transaction associated with
>   that session is committed/rolled-back

The best way to deal with this is to move your transaction boundaries to incorporate the entire process; that is, not only getting the Product but also doing whatever you want with it.

You can change the behavior of ThreadLocalSessionContext by subclassing it and re-implementing isAutoCloseEnabled() and other methods. You'd have to find a way to signal closing of the session though.

Comment: This is not exactly my understanding of http://relation.to/Bloggers/PluggableSessionManagementInHibernate31 and https://www.hibernate.org/42.html.